# Substitute only first appearance in Bash-String

Tags: bash

I've got a string `test="this is a string string"`.
Now I replace both appearances of string by using:

```
new_test="${test//string/}"
```

Instead I'd like to replace only the first appearance of string.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: `new_test="${!test//string/}"` is not working to me.

Comment: new_test="${test//string s/s}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
new_test="${test/string/}"
```

Comment: Sometimes it is very easy. Works flawless. Thank you :)

Comment: As my mother used to say, "If it had been a snake it would have bit you." :-)